# I have memory address of an struct store in int variable. Can I dereference the struct using this int value in C?

Tags: c, struct, dereference

I have address of an struct store in int variable. Can I dereference the struct??

say: int x = 3432234; // memory address of struct
now I want to access the some struct from it.

I have been suggest these steps.

1. store the address in an int variable
2. cast that int to a struct pointer
3. then dereference it

But don't know how to apply.

Comment: It's not generally safe to cast a pointer to an `int` and back; you can't be sure that it is valid when you get done.  For instance on many systems, `int` is smaller than a pointer so bits would necessarily be lost.   Why would you want to do this?

Comment: If you must store a pointer as an integer, use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` instead of `int`.  But again, use cases for this should be rare.

Comment: Cast and dereference go together in the natural way; e.g. `intptr_t x = ... ; struct foo f = *(struct foo *)x; ((struct foo *)x)->y = 42;` and so forth.  Or simply use a temporary pointer variable: `struct foo *p = (struct foo *)x; f = *p; p->y = 42;`

Comment: Why are you storing a pointer in an `int` variable?  Why not store it in a pointer?  On 64-bit machines, an `int` is not big enough to hold all the bits of an address.  It's dubious practice even on a 32-bit machine.  You'll need to cast the value to pointer type and then dereference it.

Comment: If you do have the actual address of a structure in an `int` object `x` and it can be converted back to a pointer to the structure, then you can access the structure with `((struct foo *) x)->member`, where `struct foo` is the name of the structure type and `member` is the name of a member in the structure., or you can access the entire structure with `* (struct foo *) x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `struct foo`, the easy way is to not use an `int x` but make the type a pointer-to-`struct foo`, `struct foo *x`. One can use the [arrow operator](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=expressions-arrow-operator) to access members from a valid pointer directly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo { int a, b; };

int main(void) {
    struct foo foo = { 1, 2 };
    struct foo *x = &foo;
    printf("%d, %d\n", x->a, x->b);
}
```

Sometimes, hardware requirements complicate this, but this is the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to use structs this way in mare metal environments as hardware registers are often memory mapped.

```
typedef struct
{
    volatile uint32_t reg1;
    const volatile uint32_t reg2;
}PERIPH1__t;

#define PERIPH1ADDRESS  0x56664550UL

/* OR */
uintptr_t PERIPH1ADDRESS = 0x56664550UL;

#define PERIPH1 ((PERIPH1__t *)PERIPH1ADDRESS)


 /* somewhere in the code */
PERIPH1 -> reg1 = 34;
uint32_t reg2val = PERIPH1 -> reg2;
```

if you want to store the address in the integer variable, the best type will be `uintptr_t` which is guaranteed to accommodate any pointer.

`int` is signed and on many systems not large enough to store addresses - for example 64 bits systems often have 64 bits addresses and only 32bits integers.

Comment: Sure, but you wouldn't normally have `PERIPH1ADDRESS` stored in an `int` *variable*.